# How to get pathview plot displayed directly (rather than saving as a file) in R?

Tags: r

Here is an example and the output is a png file `hsa04110.gse16873.png`. My question is how to get the plot displayed directly rather than save it as a file.

```
library(pathview)
data(gse16873.d)
data(demo.paths)
data(paths.hsa)
pathview(gene.data = gse16873.d[, 1], pathway.id = demo.paths$sel.paths[1],
                   species = "hsa", out.suffix = "gse16873", kegg.native = T)
#> 'select()' returned 1:1 mapping between keys and columns
#> Info: Working in directory D:/github/RNASeq-KEGG
#> Info: Writing image file hsa04110.gse16873.png
```

Comment: It would have been good to actually be able to download and test the data you use, so that we can reproduce the issue (and any answers).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like pathview only renders PNGs, so the trick is to define a function that will show the created PNG in the plot window and by default delete the file itself afterwards *as if* you were viewing it in memory. As an option, you can keep a copy of the PNG.

```r
require(pathview)
require(grid)
require(png)

see_pathview <- function(..., save_image = FALSE)
{
  msg <- capture.output(pathview::pathview(...), type = "message")
  msg <- grep("image file", msg, value = T)
  filename <- sapply(strsplit(msg, " "), function(x) x[length(x)])
  img <- png::readPNG(filename)
  grid::grid.raster(img)
  if(!save_image) invisible(file.remove(filename))
}
```

Now when you do:

```
data(gse16873.d)
data(demo.paths)
data(paths.hsa)

see_pathview(gene.data = gse16873.d[, 1], 
             pathway.id = demo.paths$sel.paths[1],
             species = "hsa", 
             out.suffix = "gse16873", 
             kegg.native = T)
```

You don't get any messages informing you about a written file, there is no new png in your working directory, and this picture pops up in the viewer pane:

[image]