# In R, I am trying to render plots to a byte stream rather than writing to a file

Tags: r, postgresql, graphics, plr

I have R on a headless linux server and I have NO write permissions to the file system. This has forced me down a path of wanting to save my pictures to a DB (PostgreSQL in this case).

I have searched around for a solution, but every one I find usually saves to a file first and then reads the file back into R as bytes and then store the bytes in the DB.

This stackoverflow post from 10 years ago states that all the graphic devices are file based. Has there been a change to R since then that would allow me to get the bytes?
[How to save R plot image to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045837/how-to-save-r-plot-image-to-database)

This solution looks interesting but it still requires write permissions:
[How to get pathview plot displayed directly (rather than saving as a file) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141841/how-to-get-pathview-plot-displayed-directly-rather-than-saving-as-a-file-in-r)

I had the idea to try using text.connection() or capture.output(), hoping it create a text vector that would contain the bytes of the image.

Here are the two things I tired:

```
logmodel_solar <- glm(hasfire ~ cs_rh_min + cs_air_max_temp + cs_precip + cs_solar, data=df, family = binomial("logit"))
zz <- textConnection("foo", "w")
sink(zz)
plot(logmodel_solar)
sink()
close(zz)
```

This crashes R or gives me this

```
> cat(zz, sep = "\n")
3
```

So then I tried this:

```
logmodel_solar <- glm(hasfire ~ cs_rh_min + cs_air_max_temp + cs_precip + cs_solar, data=df, family = binomial("logit"))
yy <- capture.output(plot(logmodel_solar))

>  cat(yy, sep = "\n")

> yy
character(0)
```

So I guess my questions are:

1. Does R still only output graphics to files
2. If not how do I get a hold of the bytes

Comment: It seems nothing has changed. The data still needs to be encoded in sort sort of image file format (png, jpeg, pdf) and those graphics devices currently only write to files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from a colleague who said it tooks months to figure this out. It is not intuitive but it works.

```
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Cairo/versions/1.5-12.2/topics/Cairo
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cairoDevice/versions/2.28.2
# An intermediate drawing device that can output to buffer but allows normal graphing commands to work
require(cairoDevice)

# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RGtk2/versions/2.8.7
# Allows us to interact with the GTK buffer so we can get the bytes rather than saving to disc
require(RGtk2)

########## here we read in the data and run a logistic regression model
pg = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con = dbConnect(pg, user="postgres", password="password",
                host="localhost", port=5432, dbname="fire")

query_statement <- paste("select hasfire, date_time, cs_precip, cs_air_max_temp,",
                                       "cs_air_min_temp, cs_soil_max_temp, cs_soil_min_temp, cs_solar, cs_eto, cs_rh_max, cs_rh_min, hasfire",
                                       "from final.analysis")
df <- dbGetQuery(con, query_statement)

logmodel_solar <- glm(hasfire ~ cs_rh_min + cs_air_max_temp + cs_precip + cs_solar, data=df, family = binomial("logit"))
```

################## Now we plot a figure from the model

```
# Define the size in pixels and bits per pixel of the image we want.
# We create a Gtk2 pixmap with these parameter
# In this case we are making a 500 pixel x 500 pixel image with 24 bits per pixel
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RGtk2/versions/2.8.5/topics/gdkPixmapNew
# https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkpixmap.html
pixmap <- gdkPixmapNew(w=500, h=500, depth=24)

# Now we convert the pixmap to a Cairo graphics device. After that we can use the
# Cairo device like any normal R graphic device (i.e. R plot commands draw to it)
# Cairo https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Cairo/versions/1.5-12.2/topics/Cairo
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/cairoDevice/versions/2.28.2/topics/asCairoDevice
asCairoDevice(pixmap)

#Normal plot command
plot(logmodel_solar)

# Convert out image of the plot to an RGB(A) representation in another buffer
# Since we want to go to a buffer the first parameter, dest, is null
# Next we give pixmap as the source and then we pass in the colormap from pixmap
# The first two 0s setting the origin of the image
# The next two are set to 0 because our destination is null
# The next two parameters are the width and height respectively to get from the image
# So if we wanted to subset our plot we could set different origin coordinates and smaller dimensions to get
# RGB(A) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RGtk2/versions/2.20.31/topics/gdkPixbufGetFromDrawable
plot_pixbuf <- gdkPixbufGetFromDrawable(NULL, pixmap,pixmap$getColormap(),0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 500)

# Now we convert plot_pixbuf above to a binary object that is in the format of the image we want.
# first we pass in the PixBuffer from above, then we choose our conversion format
# Values for the format are currently "jpeg", "tiff", "png", "ico" or "bmp"
# For statistical graphs you should try to use a lossless format such as tiff or png
# The next two parameters set the option_keys and option_values respectively.
# We are not setting any so we just pass in a 0 length character vector.
# The $buffer on the end tells R we want the buffer attribute from the converted object
# https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-File-saving.html
# https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RGtk2/versions/2.20.31/topics/gdkPixbufSaveToBufferv
buffer <- gdkPixbufSaveToBufferv(plot_pixbuf, "png",character(0),character(0))$buffer

# Now we return out buffer
return(buffer)
```